how do i keep all my class elements within the panel container
I'm trying to my a flyer with a pricing tier of what you get for each tier with a corresponding image to go with it. but if you look at the code  the image and elements go beyond the white panel
container I'm trying to keep it all in it


html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
     background-color: blue;
     min-height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
 }

 .panel {
     display: flex;
     background-color: whitesmoke;
     flex-direction: column;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 960px;
     width: 100%;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-radius: 25px;
     padding: 15px;
     
 }

 .pricing-img {
     margin-bottom: 25px;
 }

 .pricing-header {
     color: gray;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .pricing-features {
     border-top: 1px solid gray;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     color: blue;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 12px;
 }

 .pricing-features-item {
     margin: 25px 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 }

 .pricing-price {
     display: block;
     color: blue;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 25px;
     margin: 25px 0;
 }

 .pricing-button {
     border-radius: 20px;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     color: blue;
     padding: 24px 50px;
     margin: 25px 0;
 }

 .pricing-button.is-featured {
     background-color: blue;
     color: white;
 }

 .pricing-button.is-featured:hover {
     background-color: aqua;
     color: white;
 }

 @media (min-width:900px) {
     .panel {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
     }.pricing-plan {
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        padding: 25px 50px;
    }

    .pricing-plan:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Price Tiers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pricing.css.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel pricing-table">

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon1.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Personal</h2>
            
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Custom domains</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity</li>
            </ul>
            
            <span class="pricing-price">Free</span>
            
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Sign up</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon2.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Small team</h2>
            
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Never sleeps</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Multiple workers for more powerful apps</li>
            </ul>
            
            <span class="pricing-price">$150</span>
            
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured">Free trial</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon3.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Enterprise</h2>
            
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
            </ul>
            <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
            
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>



I tried to turn the panel container into a flexbox in hopes that everything would just fit right inside of it but nothing worked the images and elements kept going beyond the panel container and into the body

maybe your images is too big for the max-width you set
try to set the max-width of the img element to 100%
and divide the max-width of the panel which is 960px by 4
you'll get 240px now use this to define a fixed width for the pricing-plan child

thanks a lot that helped me out i was stuck on it for a few days
